# Subset and combine elements of a list

Tags: r

I have a list of data.frames that looks like this:

```
...................................    
   $ 97 :'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:    
     ..$ row: int [1:3] 97 97 97     
     ..$ col: chr [1:3] "0" "0" "0"    
   $ 98 :'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:     
     ..$ row: int [1:3] 98 98 98      
     ..$ col: chr [1:3] "0" "0" "0"      
   $ 99 :'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:    
  ..$ row: int [1:3] 99 99 99
  ..$ col: chr [1:3] "0" "0" "0"
```

I would like to subset only $ col rows and combine that in this way:

```
............   
97: 0,0,0     
98: 0,0,0     
99: 0,1,0
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Not sure of your orientation, as you output doesn't match your "data", but maybe `data.frame(lapply(myList, "[[", "col"))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(lst,function(x) x$col))
```

Comment: If this is what OP wants, then `do.call(rbind, lapply(myList, "[[", "col"))` will also work.